# How to get the charset from an HTML page

Tags: c++, html, linux, character-encoding, content-encoding

I'm trying to get the charset attribute in any HTML meta tag.
(ie.`< meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" >`)
Is there any way to do that in C++ under linux. I was using HTML tidy as a parser but I can't get that attribute to return me anything different from us-ascii (even if the encoding is utf-8)
this is the output I got:
*.*4 Node: meta
Name attr: http-equiv
Value  attr: Content-Type
Name attr: content
Value  attr: text/html; charset=us-ascii

Comment: could you paste the code? HTML Tidy can check content-type headers for sure

Comment: You don't think the framework is translating to us-ascii before passing you the node?

Answer (score 1):

As per request of  Vinko Vrsalovic, here is the code that get that result:
void dumpNode( TidyNode tnod, int indent )
{
    TidyNode child;

    for ( child = tidyGetChild(tnod); child; child = tidyGetNext(child) )
    {
        ctmbstr name;
         switch ( tidyNodeGetType(child) )
        {
          case TidyNode_Root:       name = "Root";                    break;
          case TidyNode_DocType:    name = "DOCTYPE";                 break;
          case TidyNode_Comment:    name = "Comment";                 break;
          case TidyNode_ProcIns:    name = "Processing Instruction";  break;
          case TidyNode_Text:       name = "Text";                    break;
          case TidyNode_CDATA:      name = "CDATA";                   break;
          case TidyNode_Section:    name = "XML Section";             break;
          case TidyNode_Asp:        name = "ASP";                     break;
          case TidyNode_Jste:       name = "JSTE";                    break;
          case TidyNode_Php:        name = "PHP";                     break;
          case TidyNode_XmlDecl:    name = "XML Declaration";         break;

          case TidyNode_Start:
          case TidyNode_End:
          case TidyNode_StartEnd:
          default:
            name = tidyNodeGetName( child );
            TidyAttr att = tidyAttrFirst(child);
            while (att)
            {
         std::cout < <"Name attr: " << tidyAttrName(att) << std::endl;
        std::cout< <"Value  attr:"<< tidyAttrValue(att) << std::endl;
                att =         tidyAttrNext(att);
            }
           break;
         }
         assert( name != NULL );
         printf( "%d*.*%d%sNode: %s\n", indent, indent, " ", name );
         dumpNode( child, indent + 4 );
     }
}
void dumpHtml( TidyDoc tdoc)
{
       dumpNode( tidyGetHtml(tdoc),0 );
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       std::string toReturn("");
       TidyBuffer output;
       TidyBuffer errbuf;
       int rc = -1;
       Bool ok;

tidyBufInit(&output);
       tidyBufInit(&errbuf);

TidyDoc tdoc = tidyCreate();
       ok = tidyOptSetBool( tdoc, TidyXhtmlOut, yes );  // Convert to XHTML
       if ( ok )
                  rc = tidySetErrorBuffer( tdoc, &errbuf );      // Capture diagnostics
       if ( rc >= 0 )
                  rc = tidyParseFile(tdoc, "fuebuena.html");     // Parse the input
       if ( rc >= 0 )
                  rc = tidyCleanAndRepair( tdoc );               // Tidy it up!
       if (rc >= 0)
                  dumpHtml(tdoc);

return 0;
}